# Devise would not sign off users until I added this code. Why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

For some reason this time when I apply

```
<%= link_to "Sign Out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete%>
```

it returns a user/sign_out not found error

Digging through stackoverflow I found that by applying

```
devise_scope :user do
    get '/users/sign_out' => 'devise/sessions#destroy'
  end
```

to my **routes.rb** would allow it to work. And it did.

Afterwards, I decided to test it again, so I removed the above code, log in as the user, and magically the sign_out path link works again without the code.

What is going on here?

Comment: Add your routes file.

Comment: most likely due to a missing rails js issue or absence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replice `get` in your route to `delete`:

```
devise_scope :user do
    delete '/users/sign_out' => 'devise/sessions#destroy'
end
```

and i think that it should add other sessions action to your custom route and skip sessions controller in your devise route:

```
as :user do
    delete '/users/sign_out' => 'devise/sessions#destroy', :as => :destroy_user_session
    get '/users/signin' => 'devise/sessions#new', :as => :new_user_session
    post '/users/signin' => 'devise/sessions#create', :as => :user_session
end

devise_for :users, :skip => [:sessions]
```